# How do I convert an image with colorspace YCbCr to CMYK?

Tags: linux, perl, colors, imagemagick, color-space

I've got images that have a YCbCr colorspace.  But I want to make them CMYK.  How do I do that?  A Perl solution would be great.  A command line (Ubuntu) solution would be good.

I've tried using ImageMagick but my images come out mostly black -- in fact it looks like the colors were reversed.  Here is a sampling of commands I've tried:

```
convert -colorspace CMYK start.jpg end.jpg
convert -colorspace cmyk start.jpg end.jpg
convert -profile ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc -colorspace CMYK start.jpg end.jpg
convert -profile AdobeRGB1998.icc -profile ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc -colorspace CMYK start.jpg end.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    convert YCbCr.jpg -colorspace cmyk cmyk.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at Nelson Campos post [RGB to YCbCr conversion](https://sistenix.com/rgb2ycbcr.html) and corresponding [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nelsoncsc/sv_image/tree/master/RGB2YCbCr). Great description of the conversion process and some pseudo like source code to work from.

As already suggested by user1074259 ImageMagick also supports converting to CMYK using the `-colorspace cmyk` option.